# jwt authentication c# .net framework

Tags: docusignapi

first I am not good in English but trying to explain my problem here I use c# .net framework example and assign app.config as - use  my app integration key in ds_client_id and use DS_impersonated_guid from  admin >users menu >edit user >next  to email user guid . and use private key generated for my app but still it gives me invalid grant exception. please also explain where Key and from where their value will come.

Comment: please also explain the Key and from where their value will come. and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON Web Token (JWT) grant is an OAuth 2.0 flow that is used to grant an access token to service integrations. Each request to a DocuSign API must include a valid access token.
When you use a service auth flow, your user is not going to be prompted to login to DocuSign, but you still make API calls for the user, after consent was given for the application (which is represented by the Integration Key) to do so.
The example we have for C# should work for you. I'm not sure if that's how you started. I recommend you clone the git repo - https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-csharp-jwt-framework and then update the config with your IK as well as ensure that all the information is valid and consistent. 
"Invalid Grant" exception suggest that maybe your IK is not set correctly. There are 2 options in the "keys" page to set an IK for either flow. Make sure you have the correct checkbox checked (for implicit flow) and double check all the information.

Comment: I use the same code and tried again with Integration Key and user GUID with the private key in the example but same error again don't know where i am wrong

Comment: yes and one more thing  on link  "https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-csharp-jwt-framework/blob/master/README.md"  there is a line which states that "Your DocuSign Integration Key must be configured for a JWT OAuth authentication flow:" but when i edit or add app and integration key there is no radio button for jwt grant only has Authorization code grant and implicit grant

Comment: Sorry about your confusion. to use JWT (which we also call Service Application) all you need is an RSA key in the admin. The radio button can still be either implicit grant or authorization code.

Comment: Yeah i already generated RSA key pair and use that in jwt example app.config but

Comment: so you update everything in your code? including the userID (GUID) for the user that you make the API calls for?